# How to check the end of args array?

Tags: java, arrays, scala, args

I am writing a parser program in Scala that should read input using "args" and pars it. It doesn't matter I use:

```
   while(!args.isEmpty){ 
        if (Files.exists(Paths.get(args(j)))){
            Statement=Statement.concat(inputXml)
            Statement=Statement.concat(" ")
            println(j)
            }
         else{
            Statement=Statement.concat(args(j))
            Statement=Statement.concat(" ")
            println(j)
            }
    j=j+1
    }
```

or

```
   while(args.length !=0) { 
         if (Files.exists(Paths.get(args(j)))){
            Statement=Statement.concat(inputXml)
            Statement=Statement.concat(" ")
            println(j)
            }
         else{
            Statement=Statement.concat(args(j))
            Statement=Statement.concat(" ")
            println(j)
            }
    j=j+1
  }
```

The program gives me run time exception of array index out of bound! sending 2 values as input:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

what should I do? I am confused!

Comment: Are you modifying `args`?

Comment: Please provided a reproducible test case, we can't do much with an unclear description and two lines of unrelated code. Sorry.

Comment: @Rubbic: Then why would you expect the result of either of these comparisons to ever change?

Comment: @Oliver I don't want change I simply want to parse until the end of array and create an statement with that

Comment: @Rubbic: If it doesn't change, then you'll iterate forever.

Comment: @Oliver I have put all of that section above, how can I say stop while the input is over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

Is because you are not breaking the `while` loop; the `args` parameter never change it's size, so your `while` will go forever util `j` exceed the size of `args`.

Maybe you could try:

```
int i = 0
while (i < args.length){
    // some code here
    i++;
}
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
// some code here
}
```

If you want to iterate through all the array

Comment: Thank you I used the first solution and it solved :-)

Answer (score 3):

From what you describe, you need to iterate through your array while your index is lower than the maximum array size. If you merely compare args.length value, the loop condition will continue to evaluate to a truth value infinitely, since args.length will always be different than 0 (if not changed).

You need something along the lines of:

```
for(i <- 0 until array.length){
...
```

You can find extra information on accessing and iterating over arrays [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/scala/arrays.html#accessing-array-elements) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_arrays.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Consider iterating over `args` without using indexed references (the source of out-of-bounds error),

```
for ( arg <- args ) yield {
  if (Files.exists(Paths.get(arg))) xmlFile
  else ""
}.mkString(" ")
```

This for comprehension yields a collection of `String` which is converted to a space-separated string with `mkString`.